# I want to generate an XML file that does not need to be escaped if there are special characters

Tags: java, xml, jdom-2

Using JDOM to generate an XML file, what is the best way to avoid escaping characters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqUjo.png)

I tried. I can't find a way

```java
 public class JDomCreateXml {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /**根节点*/
        Element rss = new Element("rss");
        rss.setAttribute("version", "2.0");

        /**创建document对象*/
        Document document = new Document(rss);

        /**添加子节点*/
        Element channel = new Element("channel");
        rss.addContent(channel);

        Element title = new Element("titlt");
        /**设置内容*/
        title.setText("<国内最新新闻>");
        rss.addContent(title);

        /**调节显示格式,规范格式*/
        Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
        format.setIndent("");
        format.setEncoding("GBK");

        /**利用xmlOutputter将document生成xml*/
        XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter(format);
        xmlOutputter.output(document, new FileOutputStream(new File("jdom.xml")));
    }
}
```

I want to generate an XML file that does not need to be escaped if there are special characters

Comment: What special characters especially?

Comment: There's usually a _reason_ why certain characters need to be escaped—such as avoiding ambiguous syntax while parsing.

Comment: Hello Eagle. Can you tell us the reason you want this?

Comment: escape character@GhostCat

Comment: When generating XML, if there is an escape character, it will escape, but I don't want to escape@TT.

Comment: How do I generate XML without escaping it@Slaw

Comment: @Eagle Why is it relevant how the content in the XML file is encoded? The "value" is still the same when read by the consuming XML parser.

Comment: My problem has been solved, using the first version of JDOM@Progman

Answer (score 3):

The only way might be just even more cumbersome: a [CDATA section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html).

For the *text*:

```
3 < 4 and 5 > 4
```

into

```
<p></p>
```

XML APIs convert the text **automatically** into:

```
<p>3 &lt; 4 and 5 &gt; 4</p>
```

On extraction using an XML API the entities will be unescaped again to the original text.

But with CDATA one can do:

```
   _________               ___
<p><![CDATA[3 < 4 and 5 > 4]]></p>
```

Using for instance `org.w3c.Element` then not add a `Text` child node, but a `CDATASection` child node.

The `<[CDATA[` ... `]]>` is used for raw text.

Comment: The only thing one cannot have within the CDATA section, is the string `]]>` (which should of course be extremely rare).